# How to modify response body before caching inside a service worker?

Tags: javascript, response, httpresponse, service-worker, service-worker-events

I thought it would be rather simple but I am struggle to successfully send response then modify my cloned response that is being stored in cache inside my service worker.

Ultimately I want to appended my cached data with the time and date of the fetch.  I am using my service worker to first fetch this data from the network and if its not available fallback to the cache.

This is the code from my service worker

```
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(event.request)
            .then(function(e) {

                console.log('response', e)
                var responseToCache = e.clone();

                responseToCache.json().then(function(data) {
                    var today = new Date();
                    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
                    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
                    data.cached = { date: date, time: time }
                    return data
                })

                // var init = {
                //     status: response.status,
                //     statusText: response.statusText,
                //     headers: { 'X-Foo': 'My Custom Header' }
                // };

                // response.headers.forEach(function(v, k) {
                //     init.headers[k] = v;
                // });

                // var responseToCache = response.text().then(function(body) {
                //     var today = new Date();
                //     var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
                //     var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
                //     var bodyObj = JSON.parse(body)

                //     bodyObj.cached = { date: date, time: time }
                //     body = JSON.stringify(bodyObj)

                //     return new Response(body, init);
                // });

                caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                    .then(function(cache) {
                        cache.put(requestURL, responseToCache);
                    });

                return e
            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log('data offline')
                return caches.match(requestURL);
            })
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should work

```
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request)
        .then(async function (originalResponse) {
            console.log('originalResponse', originalResponse)
            // consume the original response, and create a new one to return to the browser
            const originalData = await originalResponse.json();
            
            var today = new Date();
            var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
            var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
            const modifiedData = { 
                ...originalData,
                cached: {date: date, time: time }
            }
            const newResponse = new Response(JSON.stringify(originalData), {
                status: originalResponse.status,
                statusText: originalResponse.statusText,
                headers: originalResponse.headers
            });
            const responseToCache = new Response(JSON.stringify(modifiedData), {
                status: originalResponse.status,
                statusText: originalResponse.statusText,
                headers: originalResponse.headers
            });

            return caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                    cache.put(requestURL, responseToCache);
                    return originalResponse
                });
        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.log('data offline')
            return caches.match(requestURL);
        })
    );
```

What does it do?

1. consumes the json from the original response.
2. modifies the data.
3. creates two responses: 1 for cached data, 1 for non-cached data.
4. return the addingToCache promise, which adds the response with cached data to the cache.
5. resolve to the original response.

Basically, you want to cache a response that is different from the actual response, so, create a new one. Note that I did not test